# Excel 2016 Pivot table format not preserved on format pasting

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to preserve the Excel pivot table cell formats.

I have tried the Pivot Options

1. Autofit column widths on update
2. Preserve cell formatting on update

This does work for the cells which have been manually formatted but doesn't work for the cells on which format was pasted using Paste Special option or via format painter.

I need custom formatting for pivot cells. I'm using `VBA` to copy formatted cells stored in a separate sheet.

However even after using the options mentioned above all the formatting disappears once the pivot is refreshed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Colors, borders, there are borders which are for group of columns only, so I have to use the stored formatting.

Comment: If you are already using VBA, I'd recommend using VBA to set the formatting, instead of pasting it.

Comment: @OldUgly, It can be too much in code to set (borders (left, top, down, right and border width), font (size, type, color), cell background color. Even if I do it somehow, if a modification is required, then it would take time.